# How to prevent Xcode 9 close bracket automatically when open bracket then type something

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I've move to Xcode 9 for some days and it's has a little different with Xcode 8.
Whenever I open a square bracket for a function like `[self addSubview:abc];`

I notice that Xcode 9 auto insert close square bracket after I type `[s`. In Xcode 8 the bracket only really insert after press `;`or use right arrow key or tab key. 
It happened with brackets too, and it's a little bit annoyed.
Does Xcode 9 have a setting to turn it off?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a way to stop it completely, but when it comes to Objective-C methods, you can disable it by going to **Xcode > Preferences > Text Editing** under "**Editing**" uncheck "Automatically insert closing braces("}")"

I hope this solves your problem
[image]